# Why is my IBOutlet nil when using LoadNibNamed(), and how can I fix it?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a Mac app and I have a class derived from NSView whose contents are defined in a .xib file. I've followed the instructions in numerous posts, questions, etc., and I even reviewed working code from one of my iOS applications that works as expected. When I use my custom view in a storyboard and run the app, the outlets do not get connected. I get the following error in the console:

> [Nib Loading] Failed to connect (label) outlet from (Linkage.SidebarTextEntry) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable

Other than this error connecting the outlets, the code works fine and the custom view appears as expected in the app. It looks correct.

This is the code for loading the nib file using a protocol and an extension with the loading function:

```
protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
    static func createFromNib( in bundle: Bundle ) -> NSView
}

extension NibLoadable where Self: NSView {
    static var nibName: String {
        return String( describing: Self.self )
    }

    static func createFromNib( in bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main ) -> NSView {
        var topLevelArray: NSArray? = nil
        bundle.loadNibNamed( NSNib.Name( nibName ), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelArray)
        if topLevelArray == nil { return NSView() }
        let views = Array<Any>(topLevelArray!).filter { $0 is NSView }
        return views.last as! NSView
    }
}
```

This is a base class for my view class (because I will need to make a bunch of different views that have similar code that should not be redundant). it does nothing but it does exist and might be a source of the error:

```
class SidebarPriorityItem: NSView, NibLoadable {    
}
```

The class that has the outlets:

```
@IBDesignable
class SidebarTextEntry: SidebarPriorityItem {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textEntry: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var indentConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print( String( describing: label ) )
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let child = SidebarTextEntry.createFromNib()
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview( child )
    }
    
    override init( frame frameRect: NSRect ) {
        super.init( frame: frameRect )
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?( coder: NSCoder ) {
        super.init( coder: coder )
        commonInit()
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init()
        commonInit()
    }
}
```

Here is how I set up the custom class names in Interface Builder. I gave the file owner my custom class name and I did not, because of the recursion problem, give the root view the custom class name and left is as NSView:

[image]

[image]

Here is the outlet setting for the label:

[image]

There is a single child view of the root view so that I can potentially manage the intrinsic size of the custom view by using the size from that one child view (there is no way to set a height constraint on the root view).

I would like to get some help diagnosing the problem.

I have cleaned the project. I have deleted all derived data for the project. I have closed and restarted Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing the createFromNib() function from being static to non-static and adjusting the other code to work appropriately (like accessing the nibName using "Self.nibName". This is how the NibLoadable class now looks:

```
protocol NibLoadable {
    // Name of the nib file
    static var nibName: String { get }
    func createFromNib( in bundle: Bundle ) -> NSView
}

extension NibLoadable where Self: NSView {
    // Default nib name must be same as class name
    static var nibName: String {
        return String( describing: Self.self )
    }

    func createFromNib( in bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main ) -> NSView {
        var topLevelArray: NSArray? = nil
        bundle.loadNibNamed( NSNib.Name( Self.nibName ), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelArray)
        if topLevelArray == nil { return NSView() }
        let views = Array<Any>(topLevelArray!).filter { $0 is NSView }
        return views.last as! NSView
    }
}
```

And the code that calls this:

```
private func commonInit() {
    let child = createFromNib()
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview( child )
}
```